# Store model id in html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

If I have an html table with editable cells, and in `onchange` event I'm sending the new value to server. How can I store id of the model I'm changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the id in `data-id=""` attribute in html and in jquery you can fetch like that `$(this).data('id')`

Comment: Without jQuery: [`element.dataset.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Answer (score 0):

Store Modal Id using jquery

var someName = $(this).data('id');

For More you can read [this jquery dataid manual](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwjt0Pmg2NHWAhXJN48KHeEvDIkQFgg5MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fdata%2F&usg=AOvVaw0kTzvHiQduK0E86fkrqT2m)
using jquery you can print this wherever you want.